How to Simplify Power BI DirectQuery SQL and Reduce the Number of Queries sending to Database
I am using Power BI in direct query mode to create a simple table visualization that aggregates data. However, I have noticed that Power BI generates and sends two separate SQL queries to the database for this simple report. Moreover, instead of using a straightforward SELECT statement with a GROUP BY, the SQL queries contain multiple levels of subqueries, making them inefficient.
The columns in table emp are: id, level, mgrid, l1, l2, l3,l4,l5, l6, l7. It's a flatten employee hierarchy table. The ask is: Find the number of distinct l4, l5, l6 values mapped to each l2 value.
The SQL should be as simple as:
select 
   l2, 
   count(distinct l4) as l4_cnt,
   count(distinct l5) as l4_cnt,
   count(distinct l6) as l6_cnt
from emp
group by l2

But PowerBI generating below two SQLs and sending it to the database in DirectQuery mode, not sure whats going on.
Query-1

select "rows"."l2" as "l2",

        count(distinct("rows"."l6")) + max("rows"."ea448a3632b541b796945894c8baaf88..1") as "a0",

        count(distinct("rows"."l4")) + max("rows"."ea448a3632b541b796945894c8baaf88..2") as "a1",

        count(distinct("rows"."l5")) + max("rows"."ea448a3632b541b796945894c8baaf88..3") as "a2"

    from 

    (

        select "_"."id" as "id",

            "_"."level" as "level",

            "_"."mgrid" as "mgrid",

            "_"."l1" as "l1",

            "_"."l2" as "l2",

            "_"."l3" as "l3",

            "_"."l4" as "l4",

            "_"."l5" as "l5",

            "_"."l6" as "l6",

            "_"."l7" as "l7",

            case

                when "_"."l6" is null

                then 1

                else 0

            end as "ea448a3632b541b796945894c8baaf88..1",

            case

                when "_"."l4" is null

                then 1

                else 0

            end as "ea448a3632b541b796945894c8baaf88..2",

            case

                when "_"."l5" is null

                then 1

                else 0

            end as "ea448a3632b541b796945894c8baaf88..3"

        from 

        (

            select "_"."id",

                "_"."level",

                "_"."mgrid",

                "_"."l1",

                "_"."l2",

                "_"."l3",

                "_"."l4",

                "_"."l5",

                "_"."l6",

                "_"."l7"

            from 

            (

                select cast("$Table"."id" as varchar) as "id",

                    "$Table"."level" as "level",

                    cast("$Table"."mgrid" as varchar) as "mgrid",

                    cast("$Table"."l1" as varchar) as "l1",

                    cast("$Table"."l2" as varchar) as "l2",

                    cast("$Table"."l3" as varchar) as "l3",

                    cast("$Table"."l4" as varchar) as "l4",

                    cast("$Table"."l5" as varchar) as "l5",

                    cast("$Table"."l6" as varchar) as "l6",

                    cast("$Table"."l7" as varchar) as "l7"

                from "public"."emp" "$Table"

            ) "_"

            where strpos((case

                when "_"."l2" is not null

                then "_"."l2"

                else ''

            end), 'aa6c6f1c-d83f-487c-8fb3-e52445747957') > 0

        ) "_"

    ) "rows"

    group by "l2"

    limit 1000001

Query-2
select count(distinct("rows"."l6")) + max("rows"."b899be30b3d84b769a094f88077fb546..1") as "a0",

        count(distinct("rows"."l4")) + max("rows"."b899be30b3d84b769a094f88077fb546..2") as "a1",

        count(distinct("rows"."l5")) + max("rows"."b899be30b3d84b769a094f88077fb546..3") as "a2"

    from 

    (

        select "_"."l4" as "l4",

            "_"."l5" as "l5",

            "_"."l6" as "l6",

            case

                when "_"."l6" is null

                then 1

                else 0

            end as "b899be30b3d84b769a094f88077fb546..1",

            case

                when "_"."l4" is null

                then 1

                else 0

            end as "b899be30b3d84b769a094f88077fb546..2",

            case

                when "_"."l5" is null

                then 1

                else 0

            end as "b899be30b3d84b769a094f88077fb546..3"

        from 

        (

            select "_"."l4",

                "_"."l5",

                "_"."l6"

            from 

            (

                select cast("$Table"."id" as varchar) as "id",

                    "$Table"."level" as "level",

                    cast("$Table"."mgrid" as varchar) as "mgrid",

                    cast("$Table"."l1" as varchar) as "l1",

                    cast("$Table"."l2" as varchar) as "l2",

                    cast("$Table"."l3" as varchar) as "l3",

                    cast("$Table"."l4" as varchar) as "l4",

                    cast("$Table"."l5" as varchar) as "l5",

                    cast("$Table"."l6" as varchar) as "l6",

                    cast("$Table"."l7" as varchar) as "l7"

                from "public"."emp" "$Table"

            ) "_"

            where strpos((case

                when "_"."l2" is not null

                then "_"."l2"

                else ''

            end), 'aa6c6f1c-d83f-487c-8fb3-e52445747957') > 0

        ) "_"

    ) "rows"

sample report:
Power BI visual to show the aggregated data
I would expect Power BI to run one simple SQL and get the results. Do I need to do any configuration changes for DirectQuery mode? Also, when I used Postgres DB as the source, it ran two queries. Where as if I use AWS Athena as the source, it has sent 4 queries. Looks super inefficient query generation.
